# Jquery Datepicker - does not open if clicking from oneinput to the next

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have many inputs on one page that are dates and I am using Jquery datepicker.

If a user clicks on one input box, the datepicker calender shows up fine, but if the user goes from that input to a different input box without first clicking out, or first choosing a date from the first one, the datepicker calendar will now show up.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this? Thank you in advance for any responses.

Edit2: http://jsfiddle.net/H5rev/2/   Click on bottom one and then click on middle one for an example.  Thank you.

Edit: Here is some code. I have about 15 of them but here is JS and html for the fist five.

js:

```
 $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder2_tbxDeed1").datepicker({ showButtonPanel: true,  showAnim: "fold" });
        $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder2_tbxDeed2").datepicker({ showButtonPanel: true, showAnim: "fold" });
        $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder2_tbxDeed3").datepicker({ showButtonPanel: true, showAnim: "fold" });
        $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder2_tbxDeed4").datepicker({ showButtonPanel: true, showAnim: "fold" });
        $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder2_tbxDeed5").datepicker({ showButtonPanel: true, showAnim: "fold" });
```

Html:

```
                    <tr><td style="text-align:right; padding-right:5px; vertical-align:middle;">Closer sent deed</td><td><input type="text" runat="server" id="tbxDeed1" class="closingText" maxlength="10" /></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="text-align:right; padding-right:5px; vertical-align:middle;">Deed received</td><td><input type="text" runat="server" id="tbxDeed2" class="closingText" maxlength="10" /></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="text-align:right; padding-right:5px; vertical-align:middle;">Deed sent for exec.</td><td><input type="text" runat="server" id="tbxDeed3" class="closingText" maxlength="10" /></td></tr>
```

Comment: Works fine in my app... perhaps if you could post code and/or an example?

Comment: do you check that you don't have `input`s with same `id` to `class` to which you bind `datepicker`? It'will be better to post some code

Comment: @JustinEthier
edited to include code. thank you for the help.

Comment: @thecodeparadox edited to include code. thank you for the help

Comment: @thecodeparadox - Good point, there must be something different such as a naming conflict.

Comment: @thecodeparadox hi, i made an example here http://jsfiddle.net/H5rev/2/  click on third input and then the second. thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. I was using the animation "fold". Apparently this has the bug I have asked about. Changing it to slideDown has fixed the issue.

Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 1):

It works fine based on this test:

http://jsfiddle.net/H5rev/

Comment: Hmm. I edited my post to include some code I am using. Do you have any ideas why it might be different for me?

Thank you.

Comment: Does Gavin's example work for you? If so, there must be a problem with the other markup or code in your application.

Comment: @JustinEthier It does work for me. =/. Any ideas on what to look for? I have been trying to figure it out for a while. It's a very large application that I did not build, but I believe I have looked through everything that would effect these input fields.

Comment: @JustinEthier Try this http://jsfiddle.net/H5rev/2/  Click on the bottom one, and then click on the middle one. It does not seem to pop up on the middle one for me after clicking on the last one, unless i click out of the box or select a date first.

Comment: @user1308743 - See my answer; the problem is with the `showAnim` option.